# Product before save old related products list

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer

I created an observer on catalog_product_save_before and want to check if any of the related products have been removed

```
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();  

    $product->getRelatedProductCollection();
```

has the new related products but,

```
    $product->getOrigData();
```

Does not seem to have the original related products from before save, is there a way for me to get it?